# How get the property "has scripting terminology" of an application in Swift

Tags: swift, applescript

How get the property "has scripting terminology" of an application ?

In Applescript it's possible do this like this

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to get has scripting terminology
```

but how can I get this in Swift?

Comment: In the same way? You can run AppleScript from Swift.

Comment: I don't want to run AppleScript if possible

Comment: I do not use `swift`, so I'm spitballing here... Could you query an _application_'s `Info.plist` _file_, which would have entries, e.g.: `NSAppleScriptEnabled = Yes` and `OSAScriptingDefinition = "Safari.sdef"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [user3439894](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439894/user3439894) you're right

The code below answer this question

```
func appHasScriptingTerminology(app: NSRunningApplication) -> Bool?{
    guard let infoPlist = Bundle.init(url: app.bundleURL!)?.infoDictionary else {
        //can't get Info.plist
        return nil
    }
    if infoPlist["OSAScriptingDefinition"] != nil{
        let scriptableValue = infoPlist["NSAppleScriptEnabled"]
        if scriptableValue as? Int == 1 || scriptableValue as? String == "Yes" || scriptableValue as? Bool == true{
            //has Scripting Terminology
            return true
        }
    }
    //don't have Scripting Teminology
    return false
}
```

Comment: There is also NSURL’s `applicationIsScriptableKey` resource key.

Comment: You don’t say *why* you want to detect if apps are “AppleScriptable”, so it may be “good enough” if you don’t mind some false negatives. The `NSAppleScriptEnabled` flag should only be true for apps that use the Cocoa Scripting framework to implement their AppleScript support; older apps that predate OS X (e.g. some MS and Adobe apps) use older C APIs. Some older apps may also use old-fashioned AETE or scriptTerminology resources, so won’t contain an SDEF (`OSAScriptingDefinition`) file either. You might be better calling `OSACopyScriptingDefinition` and see if it returns a result or not.